# Maven tomcat plug in hangs

Tags: maven, tomcat, testing

I have a webapp Im trying to run integration tests on. It runs fine deployed normally into a web server. However, when doing integration tests with Maven and Tomcat plugin it hangs on this spot indefinitely.

```
Aug 28, 2015 12:14:52 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 05:39 AM'
Aug 28, 2015 12:14:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

I kind of forgot about and its been at this spot for about 2 hours now so Im sure its not a patience problem.

Here is the configuration for Tomcat and Failsafe

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>failsafe-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.3-alpha-1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-tomcat</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shutdown</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: If you can update  the complete logs of `mvn verify` then probably I  will be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to simulate your issue in my end. You need to specify `fork=true` for `tomcat7:run`. This will allow maven to continue execution after invoking the run goal.

```
   <execution>
        <id>start-tomcat</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
             <fork>true</fork>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

Comment: Actually you just nailed it... specifying fork = true fixed the issue. Kind of obvious now that you pointed it out. Thanks!